# Calling a non-exported function in a DLL in Python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I'm working in Python and trying to execute a DLL function. I can manage to execute functions by their names if they are exposed :

```
# Load DLL into memory.

hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL ("mydll.dll")

# Set up prototype and parameters for the desired function call.

hllApiProto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE (
    ctypes.c_int,      # Return type.
    ctypes.c_void_p,   # Parameters 1 ...
    ctypes.c_void_p,
    ctypes.c_void_p,
    ctypes.c_void_p)   # ... thru 4.
hllApiParams = (1, "p1", 0), (1, "p2", 0), (1, "p3",0), (1, "p4",0),

# Actually map the call ("HLLAPI(...)") to a Python name.

hllApi = hllApiProto (("HLLAPI", hllDll), hllApiParams)

hllApi(p1, p2, p3, p4)
```

But I would like to create a funcptr to an address of a non-exported function.

In C++ we can do that for example like this: (If I'm not wrong) :

```
FUNCPTR(MYDLL, myFuncName, DWORD __stdcall, (DWORD arg1, DWORD arg2, DWORD arg3), <ADDR>)
```

Does some know the equivalent of this fonction in Python ?

Merci !

Comment: If it's not exported, it's not meant to be called from outside. Please show how is the function defined.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get the address of the function somehow:

```c
// test.c
int func(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

__declspec(dllexport)
void* get_func() { return (void*)func; }
```

Then:

```py
# test.py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.get_func.argtypes = ()
dll.get_func.restype = ct.c_void_p

addr = dll.get_func()

ADD = ct.CFUNCTYPE(ct.c_int,ct.c_int,ct.c_int) # function prototype
add = ADD(addr)                                # function instance
print(add(2,3))

# In this case, can also just set the return type to the function prototype...
dll.get_func.restype = ADD
add = get_func()
print(add(2,3))
```

Output:

```
5
5
```